# php organizing result set logic to nested JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, nested, logic

I have a data base full of model numbers with varying length characters all delimited by periods.

```
Model number families:
xxxx.xx.xxxx
xxxx.xx.kjfd
xxxx.kj.jkfdk
yy.yy.a
yy.yy.b
```

and so on.

I'm trying to organize them into JSON resembling this with proper syntax of course.
Model number families:

```
{
    "name": "xxxx",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "xx",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "xxxx"
                },
                {
                    "name": "kjfd"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "kj",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "jkfdk"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have started by doing a preg_split on the model number to break the model no. down into it's components.  Then I have tried to compare the first characters before the period to the previous one and my brain freezes up and I think, "there has to be a better way to organize these."

Would it be better to store them in the DB already separated?

Thanks for any suggestions.

There is only one place to go, stackoverflow.

Comment: this is not related to the answer, but take this advice: in the future when you're using test strings, avoid doing stuff like sdsfgh, try real names instead (judging from your example), helps you see clearer

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'll make sure next time to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be better to store them in the DB already separated?

That depends. If there is a chance that you might need only pieces of that json in one place, and other pieces in other places, to avoid making 10 requests to the same json, it might be a better idea to plant them separately in the database. I personally recently hit that problem, more data which was sort of unrelated, was grouped in the same json, and I had to call that json at totally different events (save: insert/update, load, mail part of the json data on events, etc).

If instead you're going to need all of that data in one place, then put all the data in the same json.

You're going to have to decide which way to go. Neither of them is wrong, mostly because you will learn the NEXT time you have to do something similar :)

Comment: Awesome advice, thank you!  You described one of the scenarios I was afraid of.

Comment: It has been a pain in the butt to take the whole json, parse it, then update a tiny bit of information, stringify it again and replace the whole data in the database (with update of course), just because the user did a keyup somewhere. That's just wrong.

Comment: I normalized the data, so each has it's own table.  Still confused though :)  persistence!